# A plugin that makes cookies permanent?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, cookies

Does anyone know if there's a way to make the cookies permanent?

Like I'm aware that whenever I visit a website, the webmaster can give me a cookie that has a time limit, but is there a browser plugin or whatever that modifies this time limit such that it would never expire (until I explicitly edit it again)?

I'm using Chrome, but if there isn't a plugin for chrome I'm willing to look for other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be able to acheive this with a combination of

[Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg)

and

[SwapMyCookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dffhipnliikkblkhpjapbecpmoilcama)

Your problem is that you can modify a cookie with the first, but as soon as you visit a site, it will get overwritten with the "correct" details.  If you use SwapMyCookies, you could perhaps have your edited cookie stored as a profile that you can restore to revert the date back to "a long time".

Comment: a little manual.. but does the job =D